# Is ezPerm (of ez Package) an alternative for aovp (of lmPerm package)?

Tags: r, package

I was wondering if the [`ezPerm` function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ez/docs/ezPerm) (of `ez` Package) is an appropiate alternative for the [`aovp`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lmPerm/docs/aovp) (of the **orphaned and unsopported** [`lmPerm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmPerm/index.html) package)?

The `aovp` function  has been thepreferred option because it works exactly like `aov`. The `ezPerm` is faily easy to use but I am not sure if it is equivalent. And then there is the `coin` package that supposedly is able to do permutation tests, but I have failed finding a good explanation.

Comment: I only use the `ezANOVA` function of this package, which does what it is supposed to do. Moreover the package is actively maintained.

Comment: Adding to that: as the question is now stated, it can be considered as a tool request or a canditate for migration to Cross Validated.

Comment: Is ezAnova equivalent to aovp? It seems to me that ezAnova is not a permutation test, so it still have the assumptions of normality and homogenity of variances of the Anova.  I am using `lme` from `nlme` instead of aov because it allows me to see contrast with Tukey.

Comment: I am now wondering what is the difference between aov and ezAnova...

Comment: It's not that different. I find it just an easier way to specify your model.

Comment: I don't think ezAnova is a permutation test. At least, [the documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ez/docs/ezANOVA) doesn't indicate so. Therefore, normality and homogeneity of variance assumptions have to be tested. In my case, they are questionable.

Comment: I never said that `ezANOVA` is a permutation test. I only said that I use that function of the package .......

Answer (score 0):

ezANOVA is parametric approach while ezperm is considered non-parametric approach so it does not require assumptions to be satisfied.
I have not used avop, but now I am considering it as an alternative to ezPerm. I tried using ezPerm, but it takes a lot of time for big data (only good for small data), and WARNING: interactions may not be trusted using this function, this packages is still a work in progress.
Regarding aov and ezAnova, I read that the problem with ezANOVA is that it doesn’t use formulae to define the model (Taken from = Just Enough R- Anova ‘Cookbook’). I feel like ezANOVA is a better option for repeated measures, otherwise they are almost the same.